# Error "'memset' is not a member of 'std'" in g++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was trying to use the [olcConsoleGameEngine](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/Javidx9/tree/master/ConsoleGameEngine), and got this error while trying to compile the "Racing lines" program from the repository:

```
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Programming\C\C++\test>g++ -c ./src/main.cpp -I"src/include" -DUNICODE 
In file included from ./src/main.cpp:51:
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h: In member function 'int olcConsoleGameEngine::ConstructConsole(int, int, int, int)':
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:416:62: warning: narrowing conversion of '(((int)((short int)((olcConsoleGameEngine*)this)->olcConsoleGameEngine::m_nScreenWidth)) - 1)' from 'int' to 'SHORT' {aka 'short int'} [-Wnarrowing]
  416 |                 m_rectWindow = { 0, 0, (short)m_nScreenWidth - 1, (short)m_nScreenHeight - 1 };
      |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:416:90: warning: narrowing conversion of '(((int)((short int)((olcConsoleGameEngine*)this)->olcConsoleGameEngine::m_nScreenHeight)) - 1)' from 'int' to 'SHORT' {aka 'short int'} [-Wnarrowing]
  416 |                 m_rectWindow = { 0, 0, (short)m_nScreenWidth - 1, (short)m_nScreenHeight - 1 };
      |                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h: In member function 'void olcConsoleGameEngine::DrawWireFrameModel(const std::vector<std::pair<float, float> >&, float, float, float, float, short int, short int)':
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:767:93: error: 'cosf' was not declared in this scope
  767 |                         vecTransformedCoordinates[i].first = vecModelCoordinates[i].first * cosf(r) - vecModelCoordinates[i].second 
* sinf(r);
      |                                                                                             ^~~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:767:135: error: 'sinf' was not declared in this scope
  767 |                         vecTransformedCoordinates[i].first = vecModelCoordinates[i].first * cosf(r) - vecModelCoordinates[i].second 
* sinf(r);
      |
  ^~~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h: In static member function 'static void olcConsoleGameEngine::waveOutProcWrap(HWAVEOUT, UINT, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD)':
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:1198:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 1198 |                 ((olcConsoleGameEngine*)dwInstance)->waveOutProc(hWaveOut, uMsg, dwParam1, dwParam2);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h: In member function 'void olcConsoleGameEngine::AudioThread()':
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:1211:43: error: 'pow' was not declared in this scope
 1211 |                 short nMaxSample = (short)pow(2, (sizeof(short) * 8) - 1) - 1;
      |                                           ^~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h: In lambda function:
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:1238:48: error: 'fmin' was not declared in this scope
 1238 |                                         return fmin(fSample, fMax);
      |                                                ^~~~
src/include/olcConsoleGameEngine.h:1240:48: error: 'fmax' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'fMax'?
 1240 |                                         return fmax(fSample, -fMax);
      |                                                ^~~~
      |                                                fMax
./src/main.cpp: In member function 'float sSpline::CalculateSegmentLength(int)':
./src/main.cpp:146:36: error: 'sqrtf' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtof'?
  146 |                         fLength += sqrtf((new_point.x - old_point.x)*(new_point.x - old_point.x)
      |                                    ^~~~~
      |                                    strtof
./src/main.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool OneLoneCoder_RacingLine::OnUserUpdate(float)':
./src/main.cpp:290:49: error: 'powf' was not declared in this scope
  290 |                                 float d = sqrtf(powf(path.points[i].x - GetMouseX(), 2) + powf(path.points[i].y - GetMouseY(), 2)); 
      |                                                 ^~~~
./src/main.cpp:290:43: error: 'sqrtf' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtof'?
  290 |                                 float d = sqrtf(powf(path.points[i].x - GetMouseX(), 2) + powf(path.points[i].y - GetMouseY(), 2)); 
      |                                           ^~~~~
      |                                           strtof
./src/main.cpp:321:38: error: 'sqrtf' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtof'?
  321 |                         float glen = sqrtf(g1.x*g1.x + g1.y*g1.y);
      |                                      ^~~~~
      |                                      strtof
./src/main.cpp:364:52: error: 'sqrtf' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtof'?
  364 |                                 float lengthLeft = sqrtf(vectorLeft.x*vectorLeft.x + vectorLeft.y*vectorLeft.y);
      |                                                    ^~~~~
      |                                                    strtof
./src/main.cpp:398:46: error: 'sqrtf' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtof'?
  398 |                                 float glen = sqrtf(g.x*g.x + g.y*g.y);
      |                                              ^~~~~
      |                                              strtof
./src/main.cpp:418:67: error: 'atan2f' was not declared in this scope
  418 |                 DrawWireFrameModel(vecModelCar, car_p.x, car_p.y, atan2f(car_g.y, car_g.x), 4.0f, FG_BLACK);
      |                                                                   ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Programming\C\C++\test>g++ main.o -o main 
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

is there a fix for this, or is this an issue on my part?

Comment: Did you remember to `#include <cstring>`? On second look, there's a lot more undeclared symbols than what's in the title. You're likely missing several header includes

Comment: The error is in the linked repo. The author forgot to add includes that are required. (Also, using `memset` in C++ code to initialize objects is a bad idea to begin with. The author should be using value-initialization instead.)

Comment: please post a [mre] without relying on external links. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) for the headers required for standard library functions

Comment: You may workaround this by adding the missing includes youself before including the repo's header, but really, that's not a suitable question for this site. Ask the author to fix their code.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, I thought I had tried including cstring, but apparently I haven't. I also had to include math.h and placed -lwinmm in the second command (g++ main.o -o main -lwinmm)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple, I just had to add

`#include <math.h>`

`#include <cstring>`

to the start of the file.

I also had to add the flag `-lwinmm` in the second command.

Thanks for the suggestions in the comments!

Comment: Headers like `<math.h>` are C headers. C++ provides equivalent headers using a leading `c` character and without the trailing `.h`. You should include `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` in C++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The problematic header file that OP is using and linking in the question actually uses `cosf` and others unqualified, so `<math.h>` would be necessary to assure that they work as expected. In fact the file also calls `memset` unqualified occassionally, so both `#include<cstring>` and `#include<string.h>` would be required to assure lookups succeed. Of course it is on the original author for not always qualifying properly with `std::` so that `<cstring>` and `<cmath>` would be enough. (Using `cosf` is in itself weird in C++ since `std::cos` is properly overloaded for `float`.)